# Is there an updated link to Pyramid[Pylons] documentation?

Tags: pdf, documentation, pylons, epub, pyramid

I'm trying to find a link to either the .pdf or epub version of the Pyramid documentation. Both links on the website that I try time out before anything resolves.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both pdf and epub version of Pyramid docs are actually hosted on repoze.org and the domaine is being migrated to a new server, should be back online soon. By the meantime you can build it yourself as html or pdf if you get dependencies installed.

https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid

Answer (score 1):

You can find the documentation in all formats at http://www.pylonsproject.org/